# Emacs executes `c-mode-hook` twice

Tags: c, emacs

Here's my emacs config

```lisp
(require 'cc-mode)

(defun ffy-c-mode-hook ()
  "This is settings for the C/C++ mode"
  (message "ffy-c-mode-hook executed")
  (electric-pair-mode +1)
  (electric-indent-local-mode +1)
  (if electric-indent-mode
      (let ((binding (key-binding (kbd "RET"))))
        (local-set-key (kbd "RET") (key-binding (kbd "C-j")))
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-j") binding)))
  (c-toggle-hungry-state +1)
  (c-set-style "gnu")
  (setq c-basic-offset 4))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'ffy-c-mode-hook)
```

Apparently `c-mode-hook` is executed twice, because when I open a C file I see:

```
user-error: Beginning of history; no preceding item
ffy-c-mode-hook executed [2 times]
```

Is it a feature or a bug ? No other hooks are executed multiple times AFAIK. Plus it seems that now I can't toggle features in the hook.

I looked at the variable `c-mode-hook` and it its value is `(ffy-c-mode-hook)`

The versions of Emacs and CC-mode are

```
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570
Using CC Mode version 5.32.5
```

Stacktrace on `ffy-c-mode-hook`

```
ffy-c-mode-hook()
run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook c-mode-common-hook c-mode-hook c-mode-hook)
apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook c-mode-common-hook c-mode-hook c-mode-hook))
run-mode-hooks(c-mode-hook)
c-mode()
set-auto-mode-0(c-mode nil)
set-auto-mode()
```

Comment: Does this still happen if you invoke Emacs using `emacs -Q`, then evaluate the snippet above, then load a C file?

Comment: @Chris Yes. it happens. I added a stacktrace to the question.

Comment: I think this is a bug in emacs. There's a discussion here:

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16759

Comment: Interesting. So it has been out there for a while.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911266/c-mode-hook-and-c-mode-hook-appears-to-run-twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment about the bug report http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16759 I don't think that language hooks are guaranteed to be executed once for a number of language modes.  I suspect the issue is due to using `define-derived-mode` which is a lisp macro for defining a mode that already includes calls to hooks, this means the hooks called in the mode will be an additional execution.

You might want to try the initialization hook.  The manual says:

> **Variable: c-initialization-hook**
>
> Hook run only once per Emacs session, when CC Mode is initialized. This is a good place to change
>   key bindings (or add new ones) in any of the CC Mode key maps. See
>   Sample Init File.

The sample it gives is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Sample-Init-File.html#Sample-Init-File

Comment: It's very unusual for a mode defined with `define-derived-mode` to also explicitly run its mode hooks. In the (vast) majority of cases, this is left up to the macro-generated code (and modes not defined with the macro can invariably be depended upon to mimic the functionality where hooks are concerned). You might find the write-up here useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380/324105

Comment: Do you mean if it did it would be a bug?

Comment: I'd certainly argue for it to be considered a bug -- but it looks like it's already been accepted as such in the discussion you've linked to, with ideas having been put forward for how to replace the unexpected call with something cleaner (and presumably the same can be done to any other instances, should any exist).